# What compressive strength are historical Kreischer yellow brick?

Tags: brick, masonry

I've asked a variation of this question before around using soft mortar for historical brick - and I've seen variations of recommendations on using Type O mortar or some other hydrated lime mix.

However, since we know what specific brick it was, Kreischer yellow brick from Staten Island, which seems somewhat well-known, I'm curious about the actual stats for this specific type of brick and how hard it is.  I did the hardness test by the limeworks.us historical mortar company, where you run a key across the brick surface and I did not see a scratch - which translates to an nhl-strength value of 5.  I'm not sure how that translates to the more traditional mortar strength scale so am wondering if there is documentation out there.